# Multi-part component in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3

Is it possible to define a component in multiple parts and have the parent place those parts to where the parent component "wants" to have them placed.

This is kind of similar to `<slot>`s, but different in the way that not the child component decides how each `template/slot` is populated, but this logic would sit in the parent. I read about vue3 fragment which is not the right method (I understand it's only doing away with the necessity to have a 1 parent node per template) and as mentioned `<slot>`s.

Any pointer in the right directions would be appreciated.

Comment: I am using a hierarchical structure in that case: The parent component imports all child components and places them inside the parent's template at the wanted locations. If something needs to be made dynamically, I use `v-if` etc. on the parent's template. The childs can have their own childs, and the hierarchy ends at a reasonable level of granularity.

Comment: What is your purpose? Seem like you need something like [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components).
`<component :is="component" v-for="component in childComponents" />`

Comment: I use a `<component>` which is a view in a wizard (a step in a process). This view has 2 parts: the actual view and a text which should be on top of the wizard container (the parent).